# using sed and pstree to display the type of terminal being used

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I've been trying to display the type of terminal being used as the name only. For instance if I was using konsole it would display konsole. So far I've been using this command.

```
pstree -A -s $$
```

That outputs this.

```
systemd---konsole---bash---pstree
```

I have the following that can extract konsole from that line

```
pstree -A -s $$ | sed 's/systemd---//g;s/---.*//g' | head -1
```

and that outputs konsole properly. But some people have output from just the pstree command that can look like this.

```
systemd---kdeinit4---terminator---bash---pstree
```

or this

```
systemd---kdeinit4---lxterminal---bash---pstree
```

and then when I add the sed command it extracts kdeinit4 instead of terminator. I can think of a couple scenarios to extract the type of terminal but none that don't contain conditional statements to check for specific types of terminals. The problem I'm having is I can't accurately predict how many non or non-relative things may be infront or behind of the terminal name or what they will be nor can I accurately predict what the terminal name will be. Does anyone have any ideas on a solution to this?

Comment: @JoSo I have ``xterm`` in ``$TERM`` but I am using ``terminator``

Comment: I too would like a result on this.  I did a little more looking tonight and following is line under Ubuntu for example will give  though `init` - `mdm` as ancestors.  For now I reckon I can `export` some env variable like `START_TERM` in the .profile and that can give me my  *desired* result for any level of scripting or even things like a `fork()` or `exec()`.  (So far so good ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
ps -p "$PPID" -o comm=
```

Or

```
ps -p "$PPID" -o fname=
```

If your shell does not have PPID variable set you could get it with

```
ps -p "$(ps -p "$$" -o ppid= | sed 's|\s\+||')" -o fname=
```

Another theory is that the parent process of the current shell that doesn't belong to the same tty as the shell could actually be the one that produces the virtual terminal, so we could find it like this as well:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

SHELLTTY=$(exec ps -p "$$" -o tty=)
P=$$

while read P < <(exec ps -p "$P" -o ppid=) && [[ $P == +([[:digit:]]) ]]; do
    if read T < <(exec ps -p "$P" -o tty=) && [[ $T != "$SHELLTTY" ]]; then
        ps -p "$P" -o comm=
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: That will only work if run from a direct child of the terminal. (Try, for example, `bash -c 'ps -p $PPID -o comm='`. So it doesn't really address "The problem I'm having is I can't accurately predict how many non or non-relative things may be ... behind of the terminal name"

Comment: Yes I expected that. There's a solution but only if the OP would have that requirement. I actually felt wanting to provide a simpler solution first.

Comment: The quote in my comment was from the OP, so I suppose OP does

Comment: Oh I didn't notice much about the front thing. But the example problem he gave was only about anything behind the terminal.

Comment: Nice. I could have used `$(ps -p $$ -o tty=)`; it's more general than relying on dev 0 being a symlink. Always several ways to do things.

Comment: The first three commands didn't work very well but the script you gave me definately did. I was looking to put it into a script so that fit in perfectly. Thank you very much

Comment: @rici Do you mean not using process substitution and just use `<<< "$()"`? Allocating the whole output of a command on a buffer for the sake of skipping usage of FIFOs or named pipes I guess is everyone's option. The output may have been small this time but it's just my usual preference to just use <() most of the time. I got used to it.

Comment: What's the purpose of `exec`? Is there a noticeable performance gain?

Comment: @glennjackman Nothing really. Just saves the subshell from forking another process for the command, when it could just replace itself. This is also helpful if you're recording the process ID of the subshell that the command would replace and want to use it for later.

Answer (score 0):

```
curTerm=$(update-alternatives --query x-terminal-emulator | grep '^Best:')
curTerm=${curTerm##*/}

printf "%s\n" "$curTerm"
```

And the result is

```
terminator
```

Of course it can be different.
Now you can use `$curTerm` variable in your sed command.

But I am not sure if this is going to work properly with symlinks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to isolate the terminal name on your system, but as a parsing exercise, and assuming the terminal is directly running your bash you could pipe the pstree output through:

```
 awk -F"---bash---" ' NF == 2 { count = split( $1, arr, "---" ); print arr [count]; }'
```

This will find the word prior to the "---bash---" which in your examples is

```
konsole
terminator
lxterminal
```

If you want different shell types, you could expand the field separator to include them like:

```
awk -F"---(bash|csh)---" ' NF == 2 { count = split( $1, arr, "---" ); print arr[count]; }'
```

Considering an imaginary line like:

```
systemd---imaginary---monkey---csh---pstree
```

the awk would find "monkey" as the terminal name as well as anything from your test set.

Answer (score 0):

No guarantees here, but I think this will work most of the time, on linux:

```
ps -ocomm= $(lsof -tl /proc/$$/fd/0 | grep -Fxf <(lsof -t /dev/ptmx))
```

A little explanation is probably in order, but see `man ps`, `man lsof` and (especially) `man pts` for information.

`/dev/ptmx` is a pseudo-tty master (on modern linux systems, and some other unix(-like) systems). A program will have one of these open if it is a terminal emulator, a telnet/ssh daemon, or some other program which needs a captive terminal (`screen`, for example). The emulator writes to the pseudo-tty master what it wants to "type", and reads the result from the pseudo-tty slave.

`/proc/$$/fd/0` is stdin of process `$$` (i.e. the shell in which the command is executed). If stdin has not been redirected, this will be a symlink to some slave pseudotty, /dev/pts/#. That is the other side of the /dev/ptmx device, and consequently all of the programs listed above which have `/dev/ptmx` open will also have some `/dev/pts/#` slave open as well. (You might think that you could use `/dev/stdin` or `/dev/fd/0` instead of `/proc/$$/fd/0`, but those would be opened by `lsof` itself, and consequently would be its stdin; because of the way `lsof` is implemented, that won't work.) The `-l` option to `lsof` causes it to follow symlinks, so that will cause it to show the process which have the same pts open as the current shell.

The `-t` option to `lsof` causes it to produce "terse" output, consisting only of pids, one per line. The `-Fx` options to `grep` cause it to match strings, rather than regex, and to force a full line match; the `-f FILE` option causes it to accept the strings to match from `FILE` (which in this case is a process substitution), one per line.

Finally, `ps -ocomm=` prints out the "command" (chopped, by default, to 8 characters) corresponding to a pid.

In short, the command finds a list of terminal emulators and other master similar programs which have a master pseudo-tty, and a list of processes which use the pseudo-tty slave; finds the intersection between the two, and then looks up the command name for whatever results.