# Determining if the user is running a graphical interface at the present tty

Tags: bash, shell, tty

Can a shell script determine whether the user is running a graphical interface at the same tty in which the user is working?

Maybe this isn't even possible?

EDIT:

I'm actually trying to write a shell script that displays a GUI (by using zenity/yad) when the user is running a window manager on the same tty as the user is working on. Otherwise, the script falls back to a plain command line interface.

Comment: Maybe you can check the terminal capabilities and type and figure it out. What is your end goal?

Comment: @lc2817, I have added details about what I want to do.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, does it happen often to have users not using a graphical tty? Otherwise just try to launch the thing and see if it fails, if it fails, use the fallback?

Comment: If you are concerned about people connecting with `ssh` use what is described here what `tty` corresponds to `ssh` sessions: `http://serverfault.com/questions/187712/how-to-determine-if-im-logged-in-via-ssh`

Comment: Are you concerned about other cases than `ssh`?

Comment: An ssh user can set the DISPLAY environment to an available host/display (e.g. "stevesMachine:0") and then throw up new windows on their display. They may first have to open external access permissions for their display using xhost. Because of this I think how a person logged into the machine and what terminal they use may not be useful. The approach I outlined below will work for ssh users that set their DISPLAY environment to use a different host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to check the variable `TERM` or perhaps more precisely by checking the output of `tset -q`. The type of terminal would depend on it. In a normal console, it's just Linux while in most terminals it is xterm.

Other things would be to check the variable `$DISPLAY`. Most of the time it's set when you're running on a GUI terminal.

Comment: `tput` doesn't seem to have a `-q` option on Debian.

Comment: @user2064000 I'm sorry. It should be `tset -q` actually.

Comment: On RedHat I am seeing "xterm" out of tset -q whether or not I can access the display (e.g. when I use ssh to another computer). So tset does not seem useful. A non-empty $DISPLAY is necessary, but is no guarantee that a display is available.

Comment: @SteveZobell How about combining it with the variable `TERM`? Also, you can base it from the process that controls the terminal. Another thread has had similar problem like it and I had my answer there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18453471/445221

Comment: echo $TERM is yielding "xterm", whether or not the display is available. I am not sure what you mean to base it from the process that controls the terminal. Logged into ssh (bash shell) I cannot launch a new xterm. Well, I guess I can if I set the DISPLAY and use xhost to open up access to the display for the other machine. But I think that will work no matter what $TERM is. I have outlined an alternative solution that should provide a definitive answer of whether you can access the display.

Answer (score 1):

One sure way is to throw out some GUI process that will terminate right away, and check the exit status. The xterm is usually available (although the latest Linux Mint did not have it by default) and can be made to exit right away:

```
xterm -iconic -e echo test && echo "Has a display"
```

The -iconic should prevent the xterm from flashing on the display (I hope that is a general option).

Since your environment has zenity, it will also return a bad status if the display cannot be used, and output an error message. You can detect this in bash:

```
echo "" | zenity --progress --text "Display test" --auto-close 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then 
   echo "has display"
fi
```

Unfortunately the progress dialog flashes on the display for an instant. This has the added benefit of detecting if zenity itself is not available.

I have used the xterm approach in the past.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to test is whether or not a `tty` or pseudotty is present.

On linux, use the command `tty`. It will return 0 and output the `tty` file location, or return 1 (false) and print `not a tty` when it is not a tty.

The `tset -q` command can return a TERM (for instance `linux` in my case) regardless.