# Determine program that 'hosts' a script session (e.g Tilda or xTerm)?

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I'd like a way to ***know*** which *terminal* software is hosting / owns a **bash** shell session.

The requirement is to have an immutable reference or *indicator-of* a script-shell's parent.  At the moment there's a suggestion below to use:

```
   $ command=$(ps -p $PPID -o comm --no-headers)
   $ echo $command
   tilda
   #
   $ ./example.bash
   bash
```

When I put that recipe inside a script, like `example.bash` (represented above) the result is "*`bash`*", not "`tilda`".  The result I'm looking for must-not-change in that way.

At this point I believe that I'll need something in the bashrc or .profile to `export START_TERM` (*say*) if not-already-defined; such that if a script is fired by:

```
   $ myprogram &
   # starts a script like example.bash, above
   # --> command=$(ps -p $PPID -o comm --no-headers)
   # --> echo $command
   #  output should be program that created the shell process:
   #
   myprogram
```

The reason I asked about a "Terminal Manager" initially, is that this class of program is often the most common and easily  recognised use-case.  Apparently it also one of those situations where people think their requirement/use-case suite everyone else.

I gave examples from the environment variables, e.g. under Ubuntu, we might see:

```
TERM=xterm
SHELL=/bin/bash
 :
USER=will
```

`export`-ed.  And that is explicitly the level of *knowing* asked about.  So $PPID would have been idea if not that it will be different, it *shifts*, every time a script kicks off.

I believe (now) `export`-ing an environment variable in the `.profile` is a good solution.  I'm leaving the question open in case there's  a general (non-custom) method.

- *aside*: walking up a process tree (for example) will not guarantee to stop at the '*top*', that can only stop at the first program that is not-"$SHELL" (for example), what about when a bash script has called korn shell?
- Another aspect that the environment variable may not help is that a Java owner show up as "java" not the JAR file that is the program.  Something to consider later for me at least.

I use the Tilda drop-down terminal:

- [**Tilda** (*sourceforge*)](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/tildadoc.php)

And I have some useful scripts, just like everyone I guess.  I seek a method that will identify my '*terminal*' type/hose at start-up inside the: **`.bashrc`** script.

I had scant luck with Google (*who knows all*) and here on **stackoverflow** -- Hard to believe this hasn't already been Answered/Asked.

I did an experiment.  Looking at the `env` variables for different "***terminal***" (*soft*-)*emulators* / *terminal programs*:

1. [Terminal (GNOME Terminal)](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal)
2. [Tilda](http://tilda.sourceforge.net/tildadoc.php)
3. [Terminator](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jessies/wikis/Terminator.wiki)

Using the basic command:

```
  $  env > tmp/bash-Terminal.txt
  $  env > tmp/bash-Tilda.txt
  $  env > tmp/bash-Terminator.txt
```

And ran some `diff` comparisons between the 3 x pairings possible; *e.g.* ...

```
  $  diff  tmp/bash-Tilda.txt tmp/bash-Terminal.txt
```

Comparing *Terminal* to *Tilda* for example revealed that they  '*all*' are `XTERM` and minor differences like the `DISPLAY` exported:

```
  DISPLAY=:0 
  # or 
  DISPLAY=:0.0
```

Not much in it.  I did like the **Terminator** option to let me paste a *terminal number*, and of course that doesn't definitively identify that 'xTerm' as-a: **Terminator** shell either, *hmmm* ...

I'm at the point where I didn't note or see anything '*built-in*' to say what terminal emulator is in use.  The next step ...

Is to find away to "*label*" sessions in some way, during start-up.  A curious puzzle really.  Comments and thoughts welcome ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using sed and pstree to display the type of terminal being used](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18453130/using-sed-and-pstree-to-display-the-type-of-terminal-being-used)

Comment: Actually there are several duplicates to choose from (and seeing cut/paste from previous answers demonstrates that others noticed this as well).

Comment: Bespoke duplicates do NOT perform as needed when script(s) are nested with different levels and script engines.  What's needed is something that works like a C `#ifndef ...` to only once identify the *host* context (as I'm calling it).  While I believe it is not correct to just close the question -- I believe a good 80% solution is embedded in the revised description.  That way someone who has a similar need may find the `export...` notion useful.  (Under the 80:20 rule).

Answer (score 2):

You could lookup the parent PID of your shell and look at the corresponding command name.

In bash, the variable `$PPID` is the PID of your parent process.  We can get the command name like this:

```
command=$(ps -p $PPID -o comm --no-headers)
```

When running under `gnome-terminal`, I see:

```
$ echo $command
gnome-terminal-
```

And under XTerm:

```
$ echo $command
xterm
```

That seems sufficient to meet your needs.

Comment: It is a class result but only works on the terminal shell; when used in a script, the result is predictably: "**bash**" or the program calling the shell ~sigh~  I think the refinement required is to `export` something like: `SEED_TERM` in the start-up script.

Comment: Your script will always be running at the same relative position in the process tree w/r/t your terminal program.  You can walk up the parent PID path until you find it, if you want.

Comment: Actually, NO they don't.  There's a long question elsewhere on that.